# Массив и undefined(

Tags: javascript

Почему после выполнения функции из массива выскакивает сообщение **undefined?**

```js
let massive = [

function(){
alert('Кок');   
}

];

alert(massive[0]());
```

Comment: Что такое alert-e?

Comment: То есть я пытаюсь сделать алерт в алерте, поэтому и выводится undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы пытаетесь сделать `alert` в `alert-е`. Этого будет вполне достаточно:

```
massive[0]()
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, что такое alert-e?

Comment: @Человек, это же ваш код. Вы не знаете, что он должен делать?

Comment: @Человек, это `alert` в предложном падеже. На самом деле вам в комментариях хорошо пояснили, `alert` в параметрах принимает строку для отображения, а вы передаете в него функцию, которая ничего по факту не возвращает, а просто вызывает `alert`.

Comment: подробнее в ответе снизу

Comment: Значит функция должна возвращать строку, дабы alert работал без undefined?

Comment: @Человек, если вы про `alert(massive[0]());`, то **да**.

Comment: Так правильно? 

let massive = [

function(){
return "Кок";   
}

];

alert(massive[0]());

Comment: @Человек, да так сработает

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Значит функция всегда должна что-то возвращать иначе не избежать ошибок?

Comment: @Человек, нет, функции не обязательно всегда что-то возвращать, она может проводить просто операции над каким-нибудь объектом например или что-то вычислять.

Comment: @Человек,  это значит, что в alert вы всегда должны передавать строку или функцию, которая возвращает строку

Comment: "передавать ... функцию, которая возвращает строку" - ???

Comment: @Igor, а что вас смущает?

Comment: Это неправильно, или неправильно сформулировано.

Comment: @Igor,  в задаче был массив функции и необходимо отобразить сообщения (результат функции) посредством алерта. Какая формулировка будет более правильной на ваш взгляд в данном случае?

Comment: "... или результат вызова функции (которая что-то возвращает)."

Comment: @Igor, звучит лучше. Я пытался написать более просто (для новичков)

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы пытаетесь показать результат функции

```
function(){
  alert('Кок');
}
```

если не много изменить код то станет понятно почему `undefined`;

```js
let massive = [

 function(){
  alert('Кок');
  return 'Вот так' ;
 }

];

alert(massive[0]()); // показать результат вызова massive[0]()
// в вашем варианте это undefined
```

подробнее про [alert prompt confirm](https://learn.javascript.ru/alert-prompt-confirm)

Comment: А я просто вместо alert(massive[0]()); написал massive[0](); и undefined пропал)))

Comment: @Человек alert(massive[0]()) в вашем варианте это alert(undefined) потому что massive[0]() === undefined